# How I can clear the value of TextView?

Tags: android, textview

The value of the TextView is inserted by selecting the Item on List (ArrayList). When I close and open the app again the value in the TextView is still there. There is some way to clear the value of TextView?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setText("");
```

Comment: Not that it really makes a great difference but doesn't that just create a new String (empty) object eacht time filling it in there? I know it is not much but I was curious about how "clear it actually is then.

Comment: myTextView.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE) is  a  faster  of  doing this.

Comment: For some reason setting an empty string did not work for me on Lollipop. Adding a space to the string `" "` did work, but using the visibility is more elegant.

Comment: Why not set it to null instead?

Answer (score 21):

If you would like for your **hints** to show in the fields, don't set the TextView text to an empty string; instead, set it to **null**.

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setText(null);
```

Comment: This isn't accurate, at least on SDK levels 17 & 18.  Setting the value to an empty string will cause the hint to be displayed if there is one.

Comment: I tried a couple of lower api levels and still could not find where the hint wasn't showing.

Comment: IS it okay or good way to pass null to setText? will it cause any issues or exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

For that TextView use

```
android:text=""
```

in the layout

or user textView.setText("") in the oncreate() method for the activity where textView is the TextView object retrieved from findViewById()